# Singleton patterns, private methods and singleton module

Tags: ruby, singleton, access-specifier

I am fighting with singleton patterns in Ruby.

I know that singleton implements a single instance of an object but I don't quite understand if we can replicate it without the singleton module.

Then there is the issue with private methods; Right now I have to do something like this:

```
class MyTestClass
  private_class_method :new
  class << self
    def test
      puts hello
    end

    private
    def hello
      'hello world'
    end
  end
end

MyTestClass.test
```

So my questions are:

1. Is the above a good Singleton pattern?
2. Would this make sure there is only a single instance?
3. Is there a way to have private methods using the singleton module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 . Is the above a good Singleton pattern

Probably not. Using only class methods you don't get the benefit of having an `initialize` function executed for your single "instance", so it is missing some pieces you would normally find in a Singleton. Ruby is flexible enough so you can bolt on any missing features to the "class" object as needed, but it starts to look kind of ugly.

> 2 . Would this make sure there is only a single instance?

Yes. You are modifying the object which represents the class, and there is only one.

> 3 . Is there a way to have private methods using the singleton module?

Yes. Have you tried? Its just as you would expect.

```
class Test
  include Singleton
  def public_test
    "foo"
  end
  private
  def private_test
    "bar"
  end
end

Test.instance.public_test  # => "foo"
Test.instance.private_test # => throws exception
Test.instance.send(:private_test) # => "bar"
```